# How can I read properties of a BIRT report?

Tags: api, birt

I need to make a tool that analyze several BIRT reports. Therefor I need to read some of the properties of the report, like the name of the author, the title, description, and maybe others. I browsed a few hours through BIRT code, but I could not find a way to get the properties of a report. Does any of you know how to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The rptdesign file is just a XML file. Just parse it using any XML parser or even manually in your code. Should be simple enough.

Comment: I ended up in doing this. But I expect a higher level API to exist so I can say `report.getTitle()` and I don't have to care how it is retrieved or for example that the report is a XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/

Also if you have maven, then include the following artifacts

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0-v20140318-2214</version>
    </dependency>
```